# RSpec and Machinist error: Too many open files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, machinist

This morning I am having the following error:

```
  14) Deal on creation sets frozen to false or nil
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Errno::EMFILE:
       Too many open files - identify -format %wx%h '/var/folders/BJ/BJcTANEBFxWcan28U2YEKE+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20120229-36866-4l1sa8.gif[0]'
     # ./spec/support/blueprints.rb:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Specs are so damn slow (even with spork) so they are useless. It takes 9 minutes to run 20 examples in a model. Line 29 in blueprint.rb is between the following blocks:

```
Company.blueprint do
  name { "Office Tronic#{rand(10 ** 10)}" }
  website { 'officetronic.com' }
  subdomain {"officetronic#{rand(10 ** 10)}"}
  facebook { 'officetronic' }
  twitter { 'officetronic' }
  description { 'We are a company dealing with electronics and office supply' }
  address_line1 {'34 John Street'}
  address_line2 {''}
  post_code { 'EC2 3RR' }
  phone { '01 343243434' }
  city { 'London' }
  your_name { 'john Doe' }
  font_colour {'000000'}
  logo_file_name { 'mylogo.png' }  
  logo_content_type { "application/png" }
  logo_file_size { 100 }
end

Deal.blueprint do
  company {Company.make!}
  title { '50% off for web sites dev' }
  description { '50% of discount...' }
  quantity { 1 }
  min_quantity { 0 }
  start_time { Chronic.parse('one month') }
  end_time { Chronic.parse('two months') }
  price { 1500 } # in cents
  shipping_cost{ 100 } # in cents
  published { true }
  small_print { 'Some text' }
  show_map { true }
  post_code { 'E1 6BJ' }
  rrp {15}
end
```

Comment: I realised that this error happens when using spork: rspec --drb spec/models/deal_spec.rb

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Too many open files is an OS error, meaning that the OS has run out of file handles. Linux usually has a hard limit on how many files can be open at the same time, and that limit has been reached.

To increase the limit temporarily, run `ulimit -n 8192` first and then run the specs.

To increase the limit permanently, [follow these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-too-many-open-files/), and substitute `nginx` with the name of the user account that you're using to run the specs.