# Trying to start Rails app - get a lot of errors I don't understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Cannot start Ruby on Rails application - getting a lot of errors (sorry, cannot really describe it better).

OS: Mac OS X High Sierra (latest). Trying to install umessages (github link: https://github.com/cvincent/umessage/ ). I have tried to update Ruby on Rails and install all Gems available. I have ran into a lot of issues but I might have resolved some of them - but now I am stuck.

I am more than happy for any help.

Here is error message when trying to run the app:

```
bmini:umessage-master benjamin$ foreman start
20:55:23 server.1       | started with pid 48006
20:55:23 chat_polling.1 | started with pid 48007
20:55:28 server.1       | => Booting Puma
20:55:28 server.1       | => Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development 
20:55:28 server.1       | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
20:55:28 server.1       | Puma starting in single mode...
20:55:28 server.1       | * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
20:55:28 server.1       | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
20:55:28 server.1       | * Environment: development
20:55:28 server.1       | Exiting
20:55:28 server.1       | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/minissl.rb:202:in `key=': No such key file 'config/ssl/umessage.local.key' (ArgumentError)
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:171:in `block in parse'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:151:in `load_and_bind'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:96:in `run'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:70:in `run'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from bin/rails:4:in `require'
20:55:28 server.1       |   from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
20:55:28 server.1       | exited with code 1
20:55:28 system         | sending SIGTERM to all processes
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | rake aborted!
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | SignalException: SIGTERM
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:317:in `<class:Base>'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:277:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/umessage-master/lib/tasks/messages.rake:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | Tasks: TOP => messages:poll
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
20:55:28 chat_polling.1 | exited with code 1
```

Update:
We are getting closer but I got a new error now - hum, what does this mean?

```
17:48:40 server.1       |   Rendered collection of chats/_chat.html.erb [2380 times] (1674.0ms)
17:48:40 server.1       |   Rendered chats/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4687.9ms)
17:48:40 server.1       | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5056ms (ActiveRecord: 1791.9ms)
17:48:40 server.1       | 
17:48:40 server.1       | 
17:48:40 server.1       |   
17:48:40 server.1       | LoadError (cannot load such file -- action_view/template/error):
17:48:40 server.1       |   
17:48:40 server.1       | app/views/chats/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_chats_show_html_erb__3258259636189740739_70108826272000'
17:48:40 server.1       | app/controllers/chats_controller.rb:7:in `index'
17:48:40 server.1       | Error during failsafe response: Too many open files @ rb_sysopen - /Users/benjamin/umessage-master/public/500.html
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb:51:in `read'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb:51:in `render_html'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb:37:in `render'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb:27:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:51:in `render_exception'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:36:in `rescue in call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
17:48:40 server.1       |   /Users/benjamin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **ssl** error.

From [README](https://github.com/cvincent/umessage/#desktop-notifications):

> To support desktop notifications, you'll need a self-signed SSL
>   certificate in config/ssl

The developer's guide suggestion will help you.

> [Here's a good guide](https://rossta.net/blog/local-ssl-for-rails-5.html) to setting it up

**Update for new error**

`ulimit -n 8192` command may fix your problem.

Related links:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617673/2190621
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16759947/2190621
3. https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-assets/issues/339#issuecomment-251295630

Comment: Thanks @demir! We are getting closer - but now I got a new error. Yeah, I am not great at this.

Comment: @b3nis If I helped solve this problem, would you please mark my answer as an answer? You can also do upvote :)

Comment: Of course, but we still have some issues. See above.